# Hierarchical clustering with spatial Constraints (ClustGeo)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I have an attribute table with following information:
Statistical code of the commune, Air Pollution Concentrations.

I succeed in handling an entirely Ward-Hierarchical clusteranalysis in R, with the package ClustGeo.

However, I have troubles with adding the spatial constraints in the 2nd step, as I don't see how to calculate the 2nd matrix required for this, despite following the manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustGeo/vignettes/intro_ClustGeo.html).

Do I first need to add columns with geographical coordinates in the for now entirely attribute-based table? Or do you know another solution?  It's the code below that doesn't work for me.

```
D.geo <- pollution$D.geo
D1 <- as.dist(D.geo) # the geographic distances between the municipalities
```

Comment: you need to give us more information for us to be able to reproduce your example (check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Usually for the clustering you mentionend you will ned two matrix: one that give the geographical distance between point in space (that you can calculate using st_dist if your point ar spatial object created with sf) and a second matrix with another distance, that you usually use with hclust to do the hierarchical clustering.